# Is there a way to ensure that the AD entity I am reading is the most recent across different domain controllers?

Tags: active-directory, domaincontroller

We have agents that collect AD data from various DCs in the organization.the problem is that if we get an update about a change in the entity from 2 different DCs we want to know which entity change is the most recent.

We can use **timeChanged** but it only indicates the time the entity was changed on the local DC.
We also have the **usnChanged** property which is a sequence number for the entity, but again this number is per DC.

Is there a property like a global usn that we always be the same for all DCs in the same forest and can indicate about which entity change is the most recent?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you read from only one domain controller. Changes made on other DCs will get replicated to that one anyway. Then you can use `uSNChanged` to see which objects have been updated since you last checked. That's the purpose of the `uSNChanged` attribute.

From [Polling for Changes Using USNChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/polling-for-changes-using-usnchanged):

> Because uSNChanged is a non-replicated attribute, the application must bind to the same domain controller every time it runs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I collect other data not only AD info so I need to work with multiple DCs.
I need some property that is replicated

Comment: There is no such attribute unfortunately.